# Opposite of lipstick on a pig

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

There is an expression, "like putting lipstick on a pig", which means (in context) that if you take something obviously bad, no matter how many cosmetic changes you make to it, it will remain obviously bad.

Is there an expression that means the opposite? That is, if there is something obviously good, no amount of minor blemishes will take away from it.

Comment: 'Handsome is as handsome does' works for goodness of character. I'm not sure that it's totally suitable for a reliable old banger. But then I wouldn't use the lipstick simile with cars.

Comment: Some politicians were described with the word *teflon* because (at least for a period) even though others tried to besmirch their character or their actions, nothing (bad) stuck.

Comment: The problem is, there are few things that cannot be readily blemished when someone wants to do so.  Therefore there is no common idiom.

Comment: A rose by any other name would smell as sweet.

Comment: Why hasn't anyone suggested *hidden gem*? Is it wrong?

Comment: "Painting the roses red," an expression derived from a scene in Alice in Wonderland, http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Painting_the_Roses_Red, and the title of a Disney song from the movie soundtrack, carries some of that sense. Same with "killing the golden goose." Forcing something on the already perfect.

Comment: They Can't Take That Away From Me  - Written by Ira Gershwin, George Gershwin
"The way your smile just beams
The way you sing off key
The way you haunt my dreams
No, no they can't take that away from me"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe "**diamonds in the rough**" is close to what you mean.

Uncut diamonds don't look so good. But they're worth diamonds either way.

There are different variations of it.

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/diamond_in_the_rough) example:

> *The auto mechanic is a diamond in the rough, tough-talking, but honest, even generous.*

Comment: I am sorry, but I am voting against it. It seems good on first impression, but I need some convincing that it does not only apply to people, as most definitions indicate (including your linked Wiktionary entry).  [That is important since lipstick on a pig is often used in the marketing of inanimate things, like cars](http://tinyurl.com/ya4swhkx) (which is strange if you stop to think about it since pigs are animate and diamonds are not).  Also, as long as I am commenting, I would like to add that if we were looking for a word for a person, Disney's Aladdin has too good of an example to ignore.

Answer (score 1):

gild the lily

Fig. to add ornament or decoration to something that is pleasing in its original state; to attempt to improve something that is already fine the way it is. (Often refers to flattery or exaggeration.) Your house has lovely brickwork. Don't paint it. That would be gilding the lily. Oh, Sally. You're beautiful the way you are. You don't need makeup. You would be gilding the lily.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gild+the+lily

Comment: @Ynhockey Please see answer. I would stake my life on this being correct.

Answer (score 0):

One kind of object that fits the OP's description is something very old, whose historical and/or artistic value is so great that even *major* blemishes leave it of enormous value.  Thus, the phrase I suggest is:

***of incalculable value***

incalculable, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incalculable)

> not capable of being calculated

Thus, if the value of an object or a person or an experience cannot be calculated to begin with, the effect of blemishes cannot be calculated either.  Would Venus de Milo be more valuable with her arms?  By how much?